# PyQt5 - How can I add image in 'pushbutton' widget? | (not icon)

Tags: image, pyqt5, qpushbutton

Is there a function or option that adds an image in PushButton widget? In this situation, The added image means an image as a background applied to the entire widget, not an image as an 'icon'. I tried to find this option and I use the 'setStyleSheet' function, but it doesn't work. What is a problem, and how can I add an image in pushbutton?

```
btn6.setStyleSheet(
    "color: black;"
    "border-style: solid;"
    "border-width: 2px;"
    "border-color: #FFB400;"
    "border-radius: 3px;"
    "background-color: #FFD732;"
    "**background-image: url('D:\PyQt5_Tutorial\Test.png')")**
```

Comment: There are various possibilities, but: should the button still show the text? should the image be resized depending on the size of the button? if so, should it keep its aspect ratio? should the button borders be shown just like other buttons? And, most importantly, what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Please note that if you used the exact string above, the path is wrong for two reasons: single backslashes are considered escapes, so they should be `\\`, then in Qt you need to use standard slashes for paths instead (`D:/PyQt5...`) but, even more important, you should always use relative paths.

Comment: By the way, if you want to highlight a section of code, do **not** do it by using extra characters. It makes difficult to understand if your code is actually correct (as, for what we know, it could just be a typo). Use comments, or just indicate to what line you're referring to in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

You can just override `QPushButton.paintEvent()` for this. And dont forget to add interactivity to reflect different states of button: sunken, disabled, mouse hover, input focus.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

class Button(QtWidgets.QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, parent = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._image = None

    def setImage(self, image):
        self._image = image
        self.update()

class Button(QtWidgets.QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, parent = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._image = None

    def setImage(self, image):
        self._image = image
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self._image is None:
            return
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionButton()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)

        rect = self.rect()

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)

        self.style().drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_PushButtonBevel, opt, painter, self)

        if opt.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Sunken:
            rect.adjust(2,2,2,2)
        
        painter.drawImage(rect, self._image)

        if opt.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_MouseOver:
            color = self.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Highlight)
            color.setAlpha(50)
            painter.fillRect(self.rect(), color)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    button = Button()
    button.setImage(QtGui.QImage("D:\\PyQt5_Tutorial\\Test.png"))
    button.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: Oh...! Thank you for your kind answer. I resolve this problem. Thank you so much!